# Intransitive verb for "busy oneself"?

Tags: single-word-requests

It don't feel happy with the sentence

> I busied myself with the tasks around the home.

I would prefer

> I ____ [with] the tasks around the home.

where ___ represents one word.  "Occupied/concerned/engrossed myself" are similar constructions that come to mind, but are all still two words, and are especially unsatisfying because of the sneaky reflexiveness going on.

I feel like there's a word for "busied myself" that is right on the tip of my tongue.  What is it?

Comment: *I turned to the tasks around the house*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I turned to" is good.  Here are a couple more ideas:

> I *got busy with* the laundry.
>
> I *took care of* some housework.

But frankly I'm having trouble producing more candidates, only because it's hard for me to imagine being engrossed by housework.  If we replace *housework* with something more interesting, let's see what we can come up with:

> I *buried myself* in a good book.

But you don't want a reflexive verb.  Hmm.

> I *warmed* to listening to bible quotations.
>
> I *focused* on getting through my homework.
>
> I *concentrated* *on* preparing for tomorrow's lecture.
>
> I *got involved in* helping my son collect his soccer gear.